# Error create multi columns in php not use table

Tags: php

I have a sample list `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`

I want create 3 colums with format

```
1  4  7
2  5  8
3  6
```

This is my code

```
$columns = 3;
$rows = ceil(count($lists) / $columns);
foreach ($lists as $key => $value) {
   if($key % $rows == 0) {
      echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
   }
   echo $value;
   if($key % $rows == 0) {
      echo '</div>';
   }
}
```

This is result error

```
<div class="col-md-4">1</div>
2
3
<div class="col-md-4">4</div>
5
6
<div class="col-md-4">7</div>
8
```

How to fix it for result:

```
<div class="col-md-4">1 2 3</div>
<div class="col-md-4">4 5 6</div>
<div class="col-md-4">7 8</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works for your last edit:

```
<div class="col-md-4">1 2 3</div>
<div class="col-md-4">4 5 6</div>
<div class="col-md-4">7 8</div>
```

So, code is:

```
$lists = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$columns = 3;
$rows = ceil(count($lists) / $columns);
echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
foreach($lists as $key => $value) {
     if ($key % $rows == 0 && $key != 0) {
         echo '</div><div class="col-md-4">'.$value.' ';
     } else {
         echo $value.' ';
     }
}
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Thanks @Kostas. This is final result. It's work for me

Answer (score 0):

... because you're only adding the div to every third value. I think this is what you want

```
$columns = 3;
$rows = ceil(count($lists) / $columns);
foreach ($lists as $key => $value) {
   if($key % $rows == 0) {
      echo '<div class="row">';
   }
   echo '<div class="col-md-4">' . $value . '</div>';
   if($key % $rows == 0) {
      echo '</div>';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot simpler to achieve what you're after. Say you have the following list:

```
$list = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8';
```

All you'd have to do is explode your string (list) into an array and chunk that into groups of 3. Now that simplifies what you are required to do when printing out your rows:

```
$chunks = array_chunk(explode(',', $list), 3);

foreach($chunks as $row){
    echo "<div class='row'>";
    foreach($row as $value){
        echo "<div class='col-md-4'>{$value}</div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

[**Example/Demo**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#i8A2LRDsh)

---

**References**

- [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array_chunk)
- [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need fixed 3 columns, here the code (you may have to fix the code based on your column requirement)

```
            $columns = 3;
            $lists = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
            $rows = ceil(count($lists) / $columns);
            $i = 0;
            while($i < $rows)
            {
            echo "<div class=col-xs-4>".@$lists[$i]."</div>";
            echo "<div class=col-xs-4>".@$lists[$i+$rows]."</div>";
            echo "<div class=col-xs-4>".@$lists[$i+$rows+$rows]."</div>";
            $i++;
            }
```

Comment: CORRECTION: echo "<div class=col-xs-4>".@$lists[$i+$rows+$rows]."</div>";